# How to avoid Chrome crashing on parsing this JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome

I created a very simple webpage that just parses some JSON string, but somehow the browser always crashes. I use Chrome 80.0.3987.132. I tested the string with a validator and it assured that it is valid JSON. How can I debug my code to see why it failed? Is there a way to parse the JSON without failing?

Result in Chrome 80.0.3987.132 (on Ubuntu):
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Can Chrome parse JSON?</h1>

<script>
var my_json = `{
   "base":[
      {
         "params":{
            "list":[
               {
                  "description":"bla",
                  "max":0.5,
                  "min":0.0,
                  "name":"bla",
                  "stepsize":0.01,
                  "type":"float",
                  "unit":"M"
               },
               {
                  "description":"bla",
                  "max":null,
                  "min":null,
                  "name":"bla",
                  "params":[
                     {
                        "description":"bla",
                        "max":15,
                        "min":5,
                        "name":"bla",
                        "stepsize":0.1,
                        "type":"float",
                        "unit":null
                     },
                     {
                        "description":"bla",
                        "max":15,
                        "min":0.1,
                        "name":"bla",
                        "stepsize":0.01,
                        "type":"float",
                        "unit":null
                     }
                  ],
                  "type":"ARRAY",
                  "unit":null
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}`
JSON.parse(my_json)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Teemu The snippet in the question literally shows [this icon](https://i.imgur.com/ZyQ58sG.png).

Comment: I un-snippeted the code section because [user RomsBay reported a loss of data in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616469/1115360), and we don't want that to happen so easily to other users.

Comment: Why are you putting your JSON into the document in string form, only to then parse it as JSON yourself? Why not `var my_json = { "base":[ …` to begin with? (Which appears to work fine btw.)

Comment: How about some other (maybe simpler) JSON created with a template literal, does a such also crash Chrome (don't have Chrome at hands rigth now)

Comment: @CBroe I created this simple page because my browser was always crashing when I tried to read data from a server.

Comment: @Teemu there are some combinations of JSON properties that crash the browser, others don't.

Comment: Same on Windows (Chrome 80.0.3987.132). If you paste this code in the Console, it breaks as well. But if you remove any field, it passes. Then, after it passes, re-paste the original code and it passes. It should be reported to Chrome team. I am afraid it is not a thing to be solved on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Without wrapping it into a template literal, but using it as _code_ directly, it appears to work fine, no crashes: https://jsfiddle.net/8tn6yc3u/

Comment: @CBroe your code does not parse a JSON string like it is returned from a web server.

Comment: I have the same version of Chrome as E. Zacarias and I got the same results. There were no issues in an older version (Chromium 78.0.3904.108) though.

Answer (score -1):

Actually this is really weird but if you removed the second `"unit":null` it will work, I have no idea why though but try this JSON:

```
{
  "base": [
    {
      "params": {
        "list": [
          {
            "description": "bla",
            "max": 0.5,
            "min": 0,
            "name": "bla",
            "stepsize": 0.01,
            "type": "float",
            "unit": "M"
          },
          {
            "description": "bla",
            "max": null,
            "min": null,
            "name": "bla",
            "params": [
              {
                "description": "bla",
                "max": 15,
                "min": 5,
                "name": "bla",
                "stepsize": 0.1,
                "type": "float",
                "unit": null
              },
              {
                "description": "bla",
                "max": 15,
                "min": 0.1,
                "name": "bla2",
                "stepsize": 1,
                "type": "float"
              }
            ],
            "type": "ARRAY",
            "unit": null
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```